# How did Pharaoh find out that Sarai was Abram's wife?

Tags: genesis

> Genesis 12:14 When Abram came to Egypt, the Egyptians saw that Sarai was a very beautiful woman. 15And when Pharaoh’s officials saw her, they praised her to Pharaoh, and she was taken into his palace. 16He treated Abram well for her sake, and Abram acquired sheep and cattle, male and female donkeys, male and female servants, and camels.
>
> 17But the Lord inflicted serious diseases on Pharaoh and his household because of Abram’s wife Sarai. 18So Pharaoh summoned Abram. “What have you done to me?” he said. “**Why didn’t you tell me she was your wife?** 19Why did you say, ‘She is my sister,’ so that I took her to be my wife? Now then, here is your wife. Take her and go!” 20Then Pharaoh gave orders about Abram to his men, and they sent him on his way, with his wife and everything he had.

How did Pharoah know the truth?

Did Sarai sleep with Pharoah?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How did Pharaoh find out that Sarai was Abram's wife?

In short, the scriptures are silent in this matter.

There is a second, similar account in Genesis chapter 20. This time it is the king of Gerar Abimelech that takes Sarai. But in this case, the scriptures tell us:

> But God came to Abimelech in a dream by night, and said to him, "Behold, thou art but a dead man, for the woman which thou hast taken; for she is a man's wife."–vs. 3 (KJV)

So while we may not know the details in the case of Pharaoh, it is possible that God came in a dream to Pharaoh just as He did with Abimelech.

#### Did Sarai sleep with Pharoah?

Again, we don't know. But verse 19 does shed some light:

> Why saidst thou, She is my sister? **so I might have taken her to me to wife:** now therefore behold thy wife, take her, and go thy way. (bold mine)

Here Pharaoh is basically saying that he would have slept with her if he had not found out that she was already someone else's wife. In Exodus 22:16-17 and Deuteronomy 22:28-29, we see that if someone lies down (willingly or forcibly) with a virgin, the individual is to marry the virgin. This would imply that sexual relations constitute marriage.